# allow user to login from only one pc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

In my WebApp that I was building with C# .net, i want to allow the user to connect only from one pc.
so when the users logging-in in the first time i will save the pc details and when i will detect when its another pc they will not able to log in.

What I was trying to do:

**1)** save the ip when the user first log-in and check it every login, *the problem:* the ip can be change.

```
 protected string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; 
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

**2)** save some key in local storage then to check the key every log in, *the problem*: they can clear the local storage or choose to not use it or the browser will not support local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "123123");
```

There is a good and safe way to do it?

Comment: Your requirement does not make sense on a logical level. Does that mean I cannot buy a new PC as long as I run your software? You could theoretically do this, but not through a browser. You don't have access to the nitty-gritty system details that identify a machine to a level that it cannot be easily faked. Think about your requirement again.

Comment: There are 20 machines in my office and they would all present you with the same IP address (NAT) ... Browsers happily synchronise local storage data/cookies across machines these days. Perhaps you can explain *why* you want to do this? As has been mentioned its a really odd requirement.

Comment: I am curious to know, why are we trying to reengineer a browser based application to a window application?

Comment: I need to do it because my costumers pay me per user. But with the same user details they can use for two or more peoples (and its happening), another reason is that they can give the user details to my competition to get ideas or copy from me... I want to prevent them to do all of this... The costumers are big organizations so I cant use IP thanks @Alex K.

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent multiple open sessions from a single user, that is relatively simple compared to all this "one computer" business.  I don't know ASP.NET, but presumably there's a notion of a session (tracked by a session ID cookie) that will eventually time out after a period of disuse.  Just keep track of which session is the active one for each user and don't allow a second login from a user with an active session.

Comment: @adv12 its not only about two sessions in the same time, I dont want to allow to some one with out permission use the app with the details that some one gave him, and if I am only check the sessions i cant prevent it...

Comment: There is a trade off here of making the application less valuable to people that do pay.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with @nvoight that this is a very strange and questionable plan, here's one way you could sort of make it work:

On the server side, have a database table (or some form of storage) that maps usernames to "tokens."  The first time the user logs in, randomly generate such a token, store it in the database with the appropriate username, and send a cookie with the HTTP response that contains the token.  From that point on, whenever the user tries to log in, check that the cookie matches the token in the database.

There are some obvious problems with this approach, though, like what to do if the user deletes your cookie (just like deleting from localStorage as you've mentioned).  In that case they could never log in from any computer again without contacting you to remove the record on the server side.  Similarly, the same user might try to log in from a different browser on the same machine, which wouldn't work.  Also, unless you're serving this site over HTTPS, cookies are sent in plain text and could be easily hijacked by another user on the same network.

So yes, you could cobble something together that might kind of work, but it's probably a bad thing to try to accomplish and you're likely to find only solutions that get you part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

A mac address uniquely identifies a computer, you should be able to use that to reject/allow connections.

The trick is that it can't be read from javascript, so you'd need some code that executes outside the browser's sandbox to find it - a Java applet could work.

It's kludgey because it's a strange requirement.  Why is this a Web app if it can only run on a single computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want pay per PC then a WebApp is the wrong technology.
A browser is built not to work that way.
Either change the licensing model or the technology.
If you want pay per PC then you need a thick client with activation.